# Unidentified PHP and PDO taking long execution time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP with PDO connection,

My PHP code takes 7 seconds to execute but I can't find its execution time.

Code:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

$sql = "
UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = ?;
UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = ?;
UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = ?;
600+ queries
";

$binds = array("name1",1,"name2",2,"name3",3, ... );


echo 'Total Time1:'.(microtime(true)-$time_start).' Sec'; // 0.000001 Sec
update_execute($sql,$binds);
echo 'Total Time4:'.(microtime(true)-$time_start).' Sec'; // 7.51 Sec


function update_execute($sql,$binds){
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    echo 'Total Time2:'.(microtime(true)-$time_start).' Sec'; // 0 Sec

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($binds);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo 'Total Time3:'.(microtime(true)-$time_start).' Sec'; // 0.005 Sec
    return $count;
}

// In function excution, it takes just 0.005 seconds.
```

Query Execution time: 0.005 secs.

Before `update_execute` return it show 0.005 seconds after return time is 7.5 seconds

Where PHP takes 7.5 sec?

**Update:**

`update_execute` Function is not in Loop

There are no codings between `Total time3` and `Total time 4`

Why `Total time3` show 0.005 seconds and `Total time4` show 7 seconds?

If a problem in Query then it takes time before `Total time3` execution, But coding takes time between those `echo`.

Comment: You're running over 600 queries and you're asking about execution time?

Comment: Is PDO run on the background? why its can't figure out in code. query takes 0.005 secs

Comment: What kind of tables? What is the indexing? There are a lot of things here which could cause 600+ queries to take 6 or 7 seconds.

Comment: You gave yourself an answer. After you start 600+ update queries. That's where 7.5 seconds goes. What is your problem actually? Can you describe what the code does, so maybe the logic can be changed?

Comment: @Budimir as per PHP code, its shows, my query takes just 0.005 seconds

Comment: Right, but you are measuring it in a function and that is one call. But when you take 0.005 sec * 600+ queries than you will get 7.5 seconds. You are calling that function 600+ times.

Comment: In addition to that you are executing a row count for each function, which also takes time.

Comment: Please check update

Comment: You're changes don't make a difference. You're still running 600+ queries and then setting up to perform a count (why?)

Comment: OK i am agree, 600 queries take times, so how can i make it faster just in 0.00 seconds? in query ID is primary key.

Comment: Look at the answer supplied - it is a smarter way to run a single query for what you need to do. It will take some time, you'll never get 0.00 execution time because everything takes some time.

Comment: You are also not measuring the time on the same base as you define the start time twice: `$time_start = microtime(true);` is defined outside the function and inside of the function again so the resulting elapsed times will have a different basis. You should pass in the start time into the function using `function update_execute($time_start, $sql,$binds) {... }` and pass it in between your "Time1" and "Time4" block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `id` as a primary key (if not, you should!) then you can greatly simplify your query into this:

```
INSERT INTO table
(`id`, `name`)
VALUES (?,?), (?,?), (?,?), .......
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name`=VALUES(`name`);
```

Pass in the bound parameters as ID1, name1, ID2, name2...

Running a single query will doubtless be faster than running 600 queries! However, it does assume that the records exist - if not, you'll get an inserted record with just the ID and name, which may be undesirable.

If this is a problem, you can rewrite your code like so:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET name = ? WHERE id = ?;"; // just one query!
$binds = array("name1",1,"name2",2,"name3",3, ... );

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach( array_chunk($binds, 2) as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

This prepares the query just a single time, and then executes it using each pair of values. This will also be significantly faster than rebuilding the same query 600+ times.

Comment: I don't think your second code will significatively improve anything. The bottleneck is still the 600 different access to DB

Comment: @Amarnasan You'd be surprised - of course it's no guarantee of fixing *everything*, but preparing the query is the bulk of the work so doing it only once is very much better than doing it many times.

Comment: ID is primary key, and i was using your step 2, it was taking 6+ seconds, then i change it. Insert into table is a good idea, i dont want to use it, because it increases primary key value. if last ID is 400, and i run a query with dublicate, then insert new row, its id will be 800.

Comment: But the only thing you're only doing once is setting the base sql! You are still setting the values 600 times and, what is worse, creating 600 calls to DB!

Comment: @asadapp Why is that an issue? I'm not sure it's even the case, since the ID should only increase if a new row is actually added, but even if it is incremented, what's the problem?

Comment: @asadapp But that's the reason of the "ON DUPLICATE" part of the query. There is no INSERT, but UPDATE, if the index value already exists, and it's a way to fit it all in a single query.

Comment: @Amarnasan [The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html) even explains that "A prepared statement or a parameterized statement is used to execute the same statement repeatedly with high efficiency." The whole point is to be able to execute the same query with - in this case - 600 different pairs of values efficiently.